# Java Scanner input dilemma. Automatically inputs without allowing user to type

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

**Thanks a lot for responses, I will probably stick to just adding extra input.nextLine() statements to catch any "leftovers"**

So in this code I input 2, and once it goes to the if statement it skips the "sCreateLogin = input.nextLine();" and proceeds to the next input. Probably because there is something lingering in the Scanner yet I cannot figure out why it does it and how exactly to fix it.

If I do input.next() it stops, but it just isn't good enough because if you accidentally add a space it will also skip the next input. I know I could parse it etc., but I'm still confused with this.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("(1) Login");
System.out.println("(2) Create Account");
int iAccountOption = input.nextInt();
if(iAccountOption==2)
{
System.out.println("Input desired login: ");
String sCreateLogin = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Input desired password: ");
String sCreatePassword = input.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely end of line tokens that are not being dealt with.  To fix this, after input.nextInt(); add an extra input.nextLine() to swallow the end of line tokens:

```
int iAccountOption = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
if (iAccountOption == 2) {
   .....
```

Comment: This is what I have been doing sometimes. Still wonder why it happens though :0 thanks.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it's doing this because you have end of line tokens that have not been "swallowed" or dealt with, and your next call to nextLine swallows those tokens before the user has had a chance to enter any new data. If you grab a non-nextLine token and it will always be a new line, then you will need an extra call of the nextLine method. Another solution that I think has already been mentioned is to grab the whole line with nextLine and then use another Scanner object to parse the String obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Try having a different Scanner object for String.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use either of these two ways :
1. Using BufferedReader class
1a.Use BufferedReader Class and Wrap it with the InputStreamReader Class.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
//string str = br.readLine();     //for string input
int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());     // for Integer Input
```

1b.Now since the readLine method throw an IOException, so you need to catch it. so the whole code will look like this.

```
try{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
//string str = br.readLine();     //for string input
int i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());     // for Integer Input
}catch(IOException ioe){
ioe.PrintStackTrace();
}
```

2.if you are using the Java SE6 or higher then you can make use of Console class

```
Console cons = System.console();
String str = cons.readLine("Enter name :");
System.out.print("your name :"+str);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was skipping sCreateLogin because scanner.nextLine() already had a value "\r \n".
So I changed all scanners to nextLine(). It worked out fine, but maybe it won't be the best idea.

```
package com.stackoverflow.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SO4524279 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("(1) Login");
    System.out.println("(2) Create Account");
    int iAccountOption = new Integer(scanner.nextLine());
    String sCreateLogin = "";
    String sCreatePassword = "";
    if (iAccountOption == 2) {
        System.out.println("Input desired login: ");
        sCreateLogin = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input desired password: ");
        sCreatePassword = scanner.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Login: " + sCreateLogin + "Pass: " + sCreatePassword);
}

}
```

Remember to use try catch on new Integer(scanner.nextLine())

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("(1) Login");
    System.out.println("(2) Create Account");
    int iAccountOption = input.nextInt();
    if (iAccountOption == 2) {
        input.nextLine(); // here you forget
        System.out.println("Input desired login: ");
        String sCreateLogin = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Input desired password: ");
        String sCreatePassword = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(sCreateLogin + "  " + sCreatePassword);
    }
```