# How to not skip user input after a loop

Tags: java, user-input

I'm trying to create a java program which will ask the user to input the name,qty and price of the item

here is my code

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String desc;
    List<String> description=new ArrayList<String>();
    int qty;
    List<Integer> quantity=new ArrayList<>();
    double prc;
    List<Double> price=new ArrayList<Double>();
    double amt;
    List<Double> amount=new ArrayList<Double>();

    String choice;
    int ctr=0;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Description: ");
        desc=input.nextLine();
        description.add(desc);
        System.out.print("Qty: ");
        qty=input.nextInt();
        quantity.add(qty);
        System.out.print("Price: ");
        prc=input.nextDouble();
        price.add(prc);
        amt=qty*prc;
        amount.add(amt);
        System.out.print("Add another item?[Y/N]");
        choice=input.next();
        ctr+=1;
    }while(choice.equals("Y")||choice.equals("y"));
}
```

and this is what shows in the output

```
Description: item
Qty: 2
Price: 35
Add another item?[Y/N]: Y
Description:Qty:
```

after another loop it skips the first question
how can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Scanner input dilemma. Automatically inputs without allowing user to type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524279/java-scanner-input-dilemma-automatically-inputs-without-allowing-user-to-type)

Comment: but then that will ask for a double input?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `input.nextLine();` in the end seems to work

```
       do {
            System.out.print("Description: ");
            desc = input.nextLine();
            description.add(desc);
            System.out.print("Qty: ");
            qty = input.nextInt();
            quantity.add(qty);
            System.out.print("Price: ");
            prc = input.nextDouble();
            price.add(prc);
            amt = qty * prc;
            amount.add(amt);
            System.out.print("Add another item?[Y/N]");
            choice = input.next();
            input.nextLine();
            ctr += 1;
        } while (choice.equals("Y") || choice.equals("y"));
```

Output:

```
Description: Item 1
Qty: 2
Price: 23
Add another item?[Y/N]Y
Description: Item 2
Qty: 3
Price: 14
Add another item?[Y/N]N
```

Comment: but what if the description has space?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Console class to get the user's inputs and deal with spaces.
This works as expected (including spaces in Description):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]) {        

    Console c = new Console();

    String desc;
    List<String> description=new ArrayList<String>();
    int qty;
    List<Integer> quantity=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    double prc;
    List<Double> price=new ArrayList<Double>();
    double amt;
    List<Double> amount=new ArrayList<Double>();

    String choice;
    int ctr=0;
    do
    {                      
        desc=c.readLine("Description: ");
        description.add(desc);        
        qty=Integer.parseInt(c.readLine("Qty: " ));
        quantity.add(qty);         
        prc=Double.parseDouble(c.readLine("Price: "));
        price.add(prc);
        amt=qty*prc;
        amount.add(amt);            
        choice=c.readLine("Add another item?[Y/N]");
        ctr+=1;
    }while(choice.equals("Y")||choice.equals("y"));
}
}

class Console {
BufferedReader br;
PrintStream ps;

public Console(){
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ps = System.out;
}

public String readLine(String out) {
    ps.format(out);
    try {
        return br.readLine();
    } catch(IOException e){
        return null;
    }
}   
}
```